# SQL SUM filter query

Tags: sql-server, sum

We have a table with the following information:
[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdQT1.jpg)

I need T-SQL code that receives a "start date" and "end date and would generate the invoice total, grouped by customer id and invoice type, of all invoices generated within the date range AND the total invoiced for that customer (credit and cash combined).

For instance, the result if we provide start date 01-10-2012 and end date 10-11-2012 should be:

[result_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFE7f.jpg)

This is what I have:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE, @enddate DATE    
SET @startdate = '01-10-2012'       
SET @enddate = '10-11-2012'

SELECT CustomerId, InvoiceType, SUM(Total) As Total
FROM Invoices       
WHERE Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
GROUP BY CustomerID, InvoiceType
```

It works fine, but I am unable to come up with a way to calculate the "total2" column, since I'm already grouping rows by "invoicetype".

Help, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Generate `Total2` with a subquery.

Comment: The Most straightforward way is to add a sub query in your select clause to SUM up by CustomerID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT CustomerId, InvoiceType, SUM(Total) As Total
, (
SELECT SUM(Total) FROM Invoices t2 WHERE t2.CustomerId=t1.CustomerId
) AS Total2
FROM Invoices t1       
WHERE Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
GROUP BY CustomerID, InvoiceType
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped.   You can close this question by clicking the checkmark to the top-left side of this answer.